# Cache Doctrine entities find() and findBy() results

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

I've implemented Redis caching on a Symfony2 project. Now I want to cache the results of 
find() and findBy() methods for some entities and keep them for specific TTL in Redis(like one week or until the next flush).

My questions are:

1. Do you think is a good practice to cache entities like this?
2. I was thinking to serialize the results and store them in a key something like this:

**for findBy():**

- cache_key:default:entity:entityId
- value: serialized object

**for findBy(array $criteria ...)**

- key: serialized criteria
- value: serialized result

I have an event listener for the onFlush() event, which invalidates the cache for specific entities.

Do you think is a good aproach? Is there something I should watch out for? Thank you

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things". Be sure to remember about the first one in your app.

Comment: Well primary-key access is a very fast operation in DBs and findOneBy also should be pretty fast if you have indexes on used fields. I wouldn't use result cache honestly, unless I have a real reason to

Comment: Well I don't necessarily need to cache because of the speed. Doing some tests indeed the speed is kind of the same. But I was thinking to reduce the load on the database by fetching from Redis.